# JQuery In Gridview How to Check CheckBox When Textbox changed In Same Row

Tags: c#, jquery

In GridView how can I check the cbSelect when txtBox text changed in the same row using JQuery or Javascript.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelect" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxt" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use java script onkeyup event and set the checkbox value as checked. You can use below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function setCheckBox(selectedRow) {
            var row = selectedRow.parentNode.parentNode;

            row.cells[0].children[0].checked = true;
        }
    </script>

   <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelect" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxt" runat="server" onkeyup="setCheckBox(this); "/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

you can change cell index, event and function name according to your requirement.

Comment: Hi Amit Verma, 
Thank you very much for your reply...
Your solution does work just the getting checkbox need to go another level down. 
    row.cells[0].children[0].children[0].checked = true;